# Comparing the hardness of optimizing two similar, but different expressions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

Suppose we have binary variables $y_1, ..., y_n$. To make the representation simple, we show the concatenated vector as $\mathbf{y} = (y_1, ..., y_n)$. 
Consider the two following functions: 
$$
F_1(\mathbf{y}) = h(\mathbf{y})\prod_{i=1}^ng_i(y_i)
$$
and 
$$
F_2(\mathbf{y}) = h(\mathbf{y})\prod_{i=1}^nf_i(\mathbf{y})
$$
In the first function the factors inside the $\prod$ are functions of only one variable. But in the second function, they are function of (potentially) all variables, i.e. $\mathbf{y}$.

Suppose we want to maximize these two functions with respect to $\mathbf{y}$. From computational-hardness point of view, how different are these two functions?

Update: Suppose we don't know much about properties and forms of the $g_i()$, $f_i()$, $l_i()$, $h_i()$

Comment: This is not convex optimization, as the feasible set is not convex.